# Html5 video element refuses to play

Tags: html, video

I have a html5 video embedded as follows:

```
<video controls poster="/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/screenvid1.png">

   <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Speeltuin-de-Vaan-montage-met-muziek.mp4" type="video/mp4">

   <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Speeltuin-de-Vaan-montage-met-muziek.mp4.ogg" type="video/ogg">

 Your browser does not support the video tag.

</video>
```

This works fine on the test server. However,  it doesn't work on the 'real' server. On this 'real' server, Internet Explorer 11 says "Invalid Source", and Firefox 43.0.4 says "No video with supported format and MIME type found."

I am quite positive that the source file is in the correct map and believe that the browsers find the file, but somehow refuse to play it. At least I don't see how the source file could possibly in the wrong place. It's true that I get the same error message when I change the file path into a non-existing path, but as I said, I don't see how it could be a simple case of 'file not found'. And if it is a case of 'file not found', it's not because the file isn't actually there (unless I'm tragically mistaken of course!)

Note: the only difference in the path for the source file between the two servers is that on the test server the path begins with an extra map '/wptest', because that's the submap the Wordpress site resides in, whereas on the 'real' server it resides in the root folder. After copying the site to the 'real' server, I've made the corresponding change in all relevant places for many files (e.g. images), and the files are always found. I've also checked three times that the file is actually there, in the correct map, on the 'real' server. In fact, let me upload a screen shot of the map structure as it is on the 'real' server (with  the video file selected):

http://www.test2468.nl/wptest/Screenshot%20(3137).png

[NB: On this server, the map called 'svvreewijk' always counts as the root folder!]

I've found other questions regarding this error message, but the proposed solutions seem quite complicated (like changing the format with special audio formatting software), and I'm still hoping that the issue is actually simple to resolve - especially given that the video plays without problem on the test server.

Link to the relevant page on the test server: http://www.test2468.nl/wptest/foto-vid/ (video more to the right)

Link to the equivalent page on the 'real' server:
http://www.svvreewijkdevaan.nl/nl/foto-video/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its definitely the case that the sever is returning a message saying that the file is not available as Sarah says.

Given the info in your question this might be caused by a number of things:

- different relative vs absolute paths between test server and real server (although if your other files, images etc work this looks less likely).
- the video file is very large - your server or your network may have restrictions on very large files
- there may be difference in the servers video serving capability (for example see this similar issue with mp4 on IIS: http://robwillis.info/2012/04/iis-7-404-file-not-found-when-the-file-really-does-exist/)

Comment: Thank you as well. I'll look further into it later today (esp. the link you provided). And from your answer it seems that, if I can't solve it today, it's a good idea to contact the server hoster tomorrow as well. I'll upvote the answer as well (as I did with Sarah's).

Answer (score 1):

In first case, file exists:

```
$ wget --spider test2468.nl/wptest/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Speeltuin-de-Vaan-montage-met-muziek.mp4
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 587940629 (561M) [video/mp4]
Remote file exists.
```

In second case, file does not:

```
$ wget --spider svvreewijkdevaan.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Speeltuin-de-Vaan-montage-met-muziek.mp4
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's a good test (will look into this command). But do you have an idea as to WHY the file would not seem to exist, given that - as can be seen in the screen shot: http://www.test2468.nl/wptest/Screenshot%20(3137).png - it is placed in the correct folder where it should be. The poster-image for the video, for instance, is given as the same path (with only a different file name: /wp-content/uploads/2015/12/screenvid1.png) and is in the same folder  -- and it is found and recognized without problems.... It's just the video that supposedly isn't there -- even though it is.